# Color Conversion with percent Wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, colors, wpf-brushes

I am trying to get brush color from red to green by passing %.I have a datagrid each row has a percentage value.
Is there any function like getColor(Red,Green,%) which return the color from red to green a/c to %.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  What research have you done? [ask]. Good luck.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9650049/3670437) question might help you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to looking for a converter, that is a class that implements IValueConverter interface. You need to work with WPF binding.

```
public class BackgroundConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Brush someBrush;
        // Put here your logic
        return someBrush;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually he asks for `// Put here your logic` part. :)